# Filtering received frequency signal

Tags: filter, signal, frequency, high-frequency

I’m working on a problem where I have to build a speed detector using a hardware circuit with a microcontroller. I will be using a radar motion detector module to do this. I have contacted the manufacturer B+B sensors for information regarding the application circuits with no reply as yet (https://shop.bb-sensors.com/out/media/Datasheet_RADAR-IPM-165_DBE_Rev01.pdf)

I’m looking for some advice to determine which filter to implement to ‘clean’ the received frequency. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could go about this? The received frequency will be in the GHz range I imagine due to the operating frequency being 24GHz.

Comment: Read the data shet: Application circuits for this are available on request.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence that the OP has read the data sheet.

Comment: @Andyaka I’ve contacted the seller with no reply hence why I’m asking for help here

Comment: @Andyaka I’ve literally quoted the data sheet regarding the 24GHz transmitted signal

Comment: Perhaps you could hose this module output to a PC's microphone input, and use waveform analysis tools to see what filtering is suitable.

Comment: @ThePhoton that’s one of the things I’ve asked the manufacturer. I’ve had several different conflicting bits of information regarding that. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet says,

> ...the frequency of signal originating at the mixer output is proportional to the speed: 44 Hz corresponding to a movement speed of approx. 1 km/h.

This implies that

1. There is demodulation implemented in the module (by the "mixer" that was mentioned)
2. The signal delivered to you is somewhere in the DC to kHz range.

The only filtering you would want to do is low-pass filtering, with a cut-off frequency determined by the highest speed target you need to detect. You might do band-pass filtering instead **if** you don't need to detect a stationary or near-stationary target.

In any case, 24 GHz through that 3-pin 2.54-mm electrical interface would be absurd.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help that’s exactly what I’ve needed

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the version with the integrated amplifier? If not, you need to have an amplifier at the output pin "with defined bandwidth (approx. 20 ... 900 Hz)" and a gain that will bring the 300µV signal to the level required by whatever ADC input you're using.

Those are pretty simple requirements for an amplifier.

Comment: I’ve created an amplifier by cascading two opamps, I’ve managed to get a gain of 11k to get an output of ~3.3V

Comment: @Jandy12 Sounds like you're set then.